# how to pass yfinance time limitations

Tags: python, yfinance

the code:
data = yfinance.download("AAPL", start="2021-09-01", end="2021-09-08",interval="1m")

gives back error:  "The requested range must be within the last 30 days"
is there a way to bypass that? or is there any API which allows getting this kind of information ? thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: YFinance does not return historical data in the 1m interval for a period that is greater than 30 days old. It simply does not offer this option. I believe you can retrieve these dates using the (larger) 7 days interval.